# React select wrong position for dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using react-select for options block, and for all right side select inputs it always shows dropdown under left select input. What can be cause this strange behaviour? My component with select:

```
const SelectInput = (props) => (
<Select
  {...props}
  value={props.input.value}
  onChange={(value) => props.input.onChange(value)}
  onBlur={() => props.input.onBlur(props.input.value)}
  options={props.options}
 />
);
```

And this select component I use like this:

```
<Field
  className="half-select first"
  name="yearFrom"
  options={YEAR_FROM_DROPDOWN_OPTIONS}
  component={SelectInput}
  placeholder="Min"
  disabled={!validPostcode}
  onChange={(e) => {
    handleFilter(e, 'yearFrom');
  }}
 />
```

Field is a component from redux-form package.
On this pick values is for right top select input.
[image]

Comment: How does your `Select` component looks like?

Comment: @BasheerAhmedKharoti Select is from react-select package
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

Comment: Think you have problem with css. I'm using react select, and it work perfectly. Also, install react dev tools, and look into props and state of your selects.

Comment: @degr I think so too, because values updates correct(selected value appears in right select input).

Comment: so set `position: relative` to selects.

Comment: Try setting `menuPortalTarget` prop to `document.body`